# code compiles but i get NoSuchElementException error

Tags: java, exception, stringtokenizer

This program is suppose to take a people name,sex and number of people have that name and separate name in a String , sex into a char, and number of people with the name into a int. The number of people that have the name is already calculated I just need to separate each into right categories.
Problem is the code compiles but I get an NoSuchElementException error.

File looks like this:

John,M,416

Sarah,F,414

Mike,M,413

Kate,F,413

```
    ArrayList<OneName> oneName = new ArrayList<OneName>();
    while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
        line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] fields =line.split(",");


        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
        String name = stk.nextToken();
        char sex = stk.nextToken().charAt(0);
        int count = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());


        OneName list = new OneName(name, sex, count);

        oneName.add(list);      


    }
   String personSex = oneName.get(0).getName();
    System.out.println(personSex);
    }
```

Comment: will you please provide your whole error log?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
 at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
 at NameYear.<init>(NameYear.java:44)
 at TopNames.main(TopNames.java:17)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the delimitier to comma:

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
```

Than it will work.

If you not set the delimiter it will set to `\r\n`

Answer (score 0):

When you use `StringTokenizer` as

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer("John,M,416");
```

Your text will tokenized by `\t\n\r\f`. So `stk.nextToken()` will give you `John,M,416` and if you call `stk.nextToken()` again you will get `NoSuchElementException`.

Eg:

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer("John,M,416");
System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
```

Out put:

```
John,M,416
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException...
```

So you need to use your `StringTokenizer` as follows

```
StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer("John,M,416",",");
while (stk.hasMoreElements()){
   System.out.println(stk.nextToken());
}
```

Now your out put

```
John
M
416
```

Where is the Error in your code?

```
 StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
 String name = stk.nextToken(); // this line is ok
 char sex = stk.nextToken().charAt(0); // ohh this one cause the issue
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the two parameters with `StringTokenizer` 1st is your string & 2nd the regix which need to be parse.

```
 ArrayList<OneName> oneName = new ArrayList<OneName>();
        while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
        line = sc.nextLine();
        String[] fields =line.split(",");


        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line,",");
        String name = stk.nextToken();
        char sex = stk.nextToken().charAt(0);
        int count = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());


        OneName list = new OneName(name, sex, count);

        oneName.add(list);      


    }
   String personSex = oneName.get(0).getName();
    System.out.println(personSex);
    }
```

Hope it help